# Split a file name at last occurrence 'by'

Tags: regex, batch-file

I am working on a batch script to move files from one master directory which has 1000+ files to sub folders, according to the file name, sub folders have to be created and moved accordingly. Below is the scenario/ file name format.

- title_or_work_done_by_user_name.xls

From this file name pattern, I have to pick "user_name" and create a folder for that user_name. I found similar code, but not able to break it exactly at the last 'by'.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=E:\Source"
SET "destdir=E:\Destination"


FOR /f "tokens=2*delims='by_'" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*by_*.xls" ') DO (
 ECHO %%a
 ECHO(MD "%destdir%\%%a" 2>nul
 ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\*by_%%a.xls" "%destdir%\%%a\")
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

Can some one please help me out in extracting 'user_name' by splitting it at the last occurrence of 'by_'.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DELIMS option specifies a list of *characters*, not a string. So your FOR loop will split tokens at `'` or `_` or `b` or `y`. Also, you have no way of knowing what is the number for the last token. Your design is a dead end.

**Option 1**

Here is a pure batch solution that will do what you want. I use substitution to convert the file name into a pseudo path. It is then easy to pick off the desired name. Delayed expansion is used in order to access the value of a variable within the same loop (code block) that sets it. The only tricky part is toggling delayed expansion on and off as needed so as to preserve any `!`. A FOR variable containing the `!` character will be corrupted if it is expanded while delayed expansion is enabled.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (*_by_*.jpg) do (

  %= Initialize name without extension =%
  set "name=%%~nF"

  %= Convert "Part1_by_Part2_by_Name" into "Part1\Part2\Name" =%
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%f in ("!name: - =\!") do (

    %= Only execute endlocal on the first iteration =%
    if "!!" equ "" endlocal

    %= The name might contain a dot, so need name and extension =%
    set "name=%%~nxf"
  )
  set "file=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

  %= Hide error message if folder already exists =%
  md "!name!" 2>nul

  move "!file!" "!name!"
  endlocal
)
```

**Option 2**

The logic is simpler if a subroutine is used, as it avoids delayed expansion issues. The CALL makes the code less efficient (slower), but that shouldn't be an issue for a task like this.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (*_by_*.jpg) do call :moveFile "%%F"
exit /b

:moveFile
set "name=%~n1"
for %%F in ("%name:_by_=\%") do set "name=%%~nxF"
md "%name%" 2>nul
move %1 "%name%"
exit /b
```

**Option 3**

The simplest solution is to use my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that performs regex replacement. JREPL is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: eol=:" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *_by_*.jpg ^| jrepl "^.*_by_(.*)\.jpg" "$&:$1" /i'
) do (
  md "%%B" 2>nul
  move "%%A" "%%B"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR %%a IN (

title_or_work_done_by_user_name.xls
title_or_work_done_by_digby_hill.xls
title_or_work_done_by_hook_or_by_crook.xls

) DO CALL :process %%a
GOTO :eof

:process
SET "name=%~1"

:: This is the actual processing
ECHO processing "%name%"
SET "name=%name:_by_=.%"
:loop
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3*delims=." %%p IN ("%name%") DO IF "%%s"=="" (SET "user_name=%%q") ELSE (
 SET "name=%%q.%%r.%%s"&GOTO loop
)
ECHO extracted name is "%user_name%"

GOTO :EOF
```

I've chosen to use the string `_by_` as the separator, since there are names that end "by".

Simply replace the string `_by_` with a string that won't occur (or has a restricted use) in the filename. I chose <kbd>.</kbd>  byt perhaps with sme modifications (like removing the extension from the name using `%~n` <kbd>:</kbd> could be used.

The reult is [string.]*required_name.xls

By repeatedly removing the first token using <kbd>.</kbd> as a separator, when there is no 4th+token, then the second token would be the required string.